# Save individual excel sheets to separate PDF files by VBA codes

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to save some individual excel sheets to separate PDF files and rename each file based on some fixed cells and each sheets' names, the code is as follows, but the results are not as I expected, could you please help me review if there is something wrong with my codes?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsToPDFs()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Overall", "AGRM", "AICI", "AMUI", "ARMT")).Select
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        wks.Select
        wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=Range("SavePath").Value & "\" & wks.Name & "_CYProductionReport_" & Range("ReportDate").Value, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have some formatted date in `Range("ReportDate")`, you should be using `Range("ReportDate").Text`, not `.Value`.

Comment: *but the results are not as I expected* <-- please elaborate. As currently asked, it is not possible to know what your output is, or how that differs from what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You were setting up an array or worksheets but not really doing anything with them after than. In the following, the array is just the names of the worksheets and that is used by a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to provide a parent worksheet reference.

```
Sub SheetsToPDFs()
    Dim w As Long, aSHTs As Variant

    aSHTs = Array("Overall", "AGRM", "AICI", "AMUI", "ARMT")

    For w = LBound(aSHTs) To UBound(aSHTs)
        With Worksheets(aSHTs(w))
            'the filename should NOT have a .PDF file extension!
            Debug.Print Range("SavePath").Value & "\" & .Name & "_CYProductionReport_" & Range("ReportDate").Text
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                Filename:=Range("SavePath").Value & "\" & .Name & "_CYProductionReport_" & Range("ReportDate").Text, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either of the `Select` statements. Also, presuming you have selected the array of sheets, you should not be iterating the full `Worksheets` collection.

Also using the `.Text` property, assuming the `Range("ReportDate")` contains a `Date` type, which is actually a Long Integer.  The `.Text` property will return what is *displayed* in the cell, not the underlying integer date value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsToPDFs()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim printSheets as Variant   'Array of worksheets
    Dim rptDate as String

    'Assign to the array
    Set printSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Overall", "AGRM", "AICI", "AMUI", "ARMT"))

    'Format the report date:
     rptDate = Format(Range("ReportDate").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") 'Modify as needed

    'Iterating over the printSheets array:
    For Each wks In printSheets
        wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=Range("SavePath").Value & "\" & wks.Name & _
                "_CYProductionReport_" & rptDate, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you need to `Set printSheets = ...` and the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) for **ReportDate** may be bringing in forward slashes.

Comment: @Jeeped  Ah yes that's an object array, also good catch on the date format

Comment: Thank you so much David, I used your code and it worked!!! And also thank you @Jeeped, greatly appreciated your answers!

Comment: @Ning you should consider mark one of our answers as "Accepted" if it has solved the problem.